# Show user info in the next form after Login

Tags: c#, mysql, forms

I need help, My problem is I want to show the user information in the next form like When I Login in the Starting form :

Starting form

[image: Login Form]

This is my code for Logging In :

```
 private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Boolean exist = false;
        MainForm mf = new MainForm();
        if (txtUser.Text == "" || txtPass.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Input Logon ID and Password", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel);

        }

        else
        {
            conn = koneksyon.getConnect();
            conn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select Username,Password from Staff where Username = '" + txtUser.Text + "' AND Password = '" + txtPass.Text + "'", conn);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                exist = true;

                txtUser.Text = dr[0].ToString();
                txtPass.Text = dr[1].ToString();

            }
            if (exist == true)
            {
                mf.Show();
                this.Hide();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("INCORRECT Logon ID or password", "INVALID", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtUser.Clear();
                txtPass.Clear();
                txtUser.Focus();
            }
            conn.Close();
            dr.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Now my Problem is I want to display this when I enter

Username = admin , Password = 123456 it will go to next form and show this

[![Form2][2]][2]

This is the information when I Login, How can I do this? I dont have any codes, for showing, need help! Thanks

Comment: @HiDeo thanks for editing sir

Comment: Try inputting `admin'; --` as the username - then you might realise why parameterised queries are so important. Google "Little Bobby Tables"

Comment: @MattWilko - can you show me sir, I don't have any clue on how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: You don't know how to google something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MainForm constructor, you must put some variable between Parenthesis.
i.e. in the MainForm use this:

```
public MainForm(string _staffID, string _firstName, string _lastName)
{
     InitializeComponent();

     txtStaffID.Text = _staffID;
     txtFisrtName.Text = _firstName;
     txtLastName.Text = _lastName;
}
```

Now, when you want show MainForm from another form, use this code:

```
string StaffID = "Fill Yourself as you want";
string FisrtName = "Fill Yourself as you want";
string LastName = "Fill Yourself as you want";
MainForm mf = new MainForm(StaffID, FisrtName, LastName);
mf.Show();
```

I hope this is helpful.